# Writing to WAV file C++

Tags: c++, wav

I have a homework about `WAV` files and `FIR` filters for a Digital Signal Processing class.

My program must read a `WAV` file, apply a filter to the data and write the output data to another `WAV` file again.

I have completed reading and applying filters but I can't write the `WAV` file. The program doesn't give any errors while compiling but the `WAV` file doesn't play.

If I write `"temp"` to the `WAV`, it runs properly. But if I write `"data"`, it doesn't.

How can I write a WAV file properly?

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PI 3.14f
#define WAV_HEADER_LENGTH 44

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char* read_wav(const char* filename, short*, short*, int*);
void write_wav(const char* filename, const char*, int);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
short nchannel, ssample;
int csample;

//Reading WAV file and returning the data.
char* temp = read_wav("sum.wav", &nchannel, &ssample, &csample);
short* data = (short*)&temp[WAV_HEADER_LENGTH];

cout << "How many coefficients are there in filter ?" << endl;
int N;
cin >> N ;

float filter[N];
cout << "Type coefficients in filter." << endl;
for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
    cin >> filter[i];
}

short* output = (short*)&temp[WAV_HEADER_LENGTH];

for(int i=0; i < csample; i++){

    double sum = 0;
    for(int j=0; j < N; j++){
        if((i - j) >= 0)
           sum += filter[j] * data[i-j];
    }
    output[i] = (short) sum;
}

write_wav("test.wav", out, csample * ssample + WAV_HEADER_LENGTH);

}

char* read_wav(const char* filename, short* nchannel, short* ssample, int* csample) {

    //Reading the file.
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open the file \"%s\"\n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int file_size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    printf("The file \"%s\" has %d bytes\n\n", filename, file_size);

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);
    fread(buffer, file_size, 1, fp);

    // Dump the buffer info.
    *nchannel = *(short*)&buffer[22];
    *ssample = *(short*)&buffer[34] / 8;
    *csample = *(int*)&buffer[40] / *ssample;

    printf("ChunkSize :\t %u\n", *(int*)&buffer[4]);
    printf("Format :\t %u\n", *(short*)&buffer[20]);
    printf("NumChannels :\t %u\n", *(short*)&buffer[22]);
    printf("SampleRate :\t %u\n", *(int*)&buffer[24]);  // number of samples per second
    printf("ByteRate :\t %u\n", *(int*)&buffer[28]);        // number of bytes per second
    printf("BitsPerSample :\t %u\n", *(short*)&buffer[34]);
    printf("Subchunk2ID :\t \"%c%c%c%c\"\n", buffer[36], buffer[37], buffer[38], buffer[39]);   // marks beginning of the data section
    printf("Subchunk2Size :\t %u\n", *(int*)&buffer[40]);       // size of data (byte)
    printf("Duration :\t %fs\n\n", (float)(*(int*)&buffer[40]) / *(int*)&buffer[28]);

    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}

void write_wav(const char* filename, const char* data, int len) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open the file \"%s\"\n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    fwrite(data, len, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: If you read the file and write it without applying any filter, can you read (and listen to) the new file?

Comment: WAV files need a header prepended, see: https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/

Comment: The line `write_wav("test.wav", out, csample * ssample + WAV_HEADER_LENGTH);` uses a variable `out` that does not exist - this is clearly not the actual code you are running since it would not compile.

Comment: Why would you not use a library to handle the WAV file formatting? Such as https://github.com/mhroth/tinywav

Comment: @vdavid If i write "temp" to WAV, i can listen new WAV file properly. But if i write "data" without any filter, i can't listen.

Comment: @Clifford sorry for my fault. I created an array named "out" and tried with that. Next, i deleted "out" but forgot to delete from "write_wav" parameter.

Comment: @Clifford thank you for library but lecturer doesn't allow us to use libraries.

Comment: is it multiplatform? what os is it?

Comment: Please edit the code so that it compiles and runs.

Comment: Also, please hard-code some filter coefficients that make the problem.  The code must compile and run out of the box.

Comment: @mmc055 So you have to fix the fault, by editing the question. We cannot answer a question about code we cannot see or about code we can see, but is not the code you are asking about!  Specifically we cannot see what you _are_ writing.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int main()
{
    short nchannel, ssample;
    int csample;

    // Reading WAV file and returning the data.
    char* temp = read_wav("sum.wav", &nchannel, &ssample, &csample);
    short* data = (short*)&temp[WAV_HEADER_LENGTH];

//    cout << "How many coefficients are there in filter ?" << endl;
    const int N = 2;
//    cin >> N;

    float filter[N] = {0.5, 0.75};
//    cout << "Type coefficients in filter." << endl;
//    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
//    {
//        cin >> filter[i];
//    }

    short* output = (short*)&temp[WAV_HEADER_LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < csample; i++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if ((i - j) >= 0) sum += filter[j] * data[i - j];
        }
        output[i] = (short)sum;
    }

    write_wav("test.wav", (char*)temp, csample * ssample + WAV_HEADER_LENGTH);
}
```

My changes:

- The major change is to use the full buffer, with extremely misleading name: `temp`, instead of your `out` that does not compile, as the argument of `write_wav`.
- I applied "my" filter coefficients (the sound from the output file is really distorted),
- I applied my favorite indentation

If the code is to be portable, you need to  check the endiannes and act accordingly.

I would expect the input and output files to be of the same length, but they're not. Please check it yourself why this is not the case.
Example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zkoza zkoza 787306 06-23 14:09 sum.wav
-rw-r--r-- 1 zkoza zkoza 787176 06-23 14:16 test.wav
```

It looks like 130 bytes are missing in the output file.

Your `float filter[N]` with `N` not known at compile time is a C++ extension: please use `std::vector` in your final code instead.

Next time please provide also a link for any input files. For my tests, I used https://freewavesamples.com/alesis-fusion-clean-guitar-c3  , but all these little things, like finding an input file (WAV format has several flavors, I could have missed the correct one), guessing filter parameters etc. take *time* and effort.

Your condition `if ((i - j) >= 0)` can be written in a way easier to understand; preferably by changing the inner loop "header".

Comment: I know "temp" works properly because program read wav and return "temp". You set "temp" as parameter, then why do we have "output" ? I should set "output" as parameter to see difference between input and output.

Comment: Of course not! Output is just a reference into temp. It's the same memory buffer!

Comment: You should allocate a separate buffer for output. I suggest it should contain the extra 44 bytes of a standard WAV header. `memcopy` these bytes from `temp` or set them manually. Then set the "sound" bytes in accordance with your filter. At the moment you use "output"  as both input and output buffer, which is essentially wrong.

Comment: `data`, `output` and `temp` refer to the same memory (with just a bit different initial offsets). Algorithmically this does not look "kosher", but as far as I could understand, you asked why your output files did not play at all. This is a different question. From our conversation I infer you might have forgotten to add the WAV header in the output file.

Comment: @mmc055 because then you'd only be writing the sample data without the metadata header.  It would then not be a valid WAV.  Since you took the trouble to read and display the header data, it is not clear why this is not obvious, and the fact that the code in the question writes neither temp nor output (until you edit as requested) it is not clear what your problem is, except your revealing comment.